# I could't find IDs of fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, findviewbyid

**XML files**

Here is the *activity_main.xml* file. that contains two fragments *fragment_list.xml* and *fragment_deatails.xml*

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="com.udemy.fragmentsapp.ListFrag"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fram2"
    android:name="com.udemy.fragmentsapp.DetailFrag"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
```

---

Here is the *fragment_list.xml* file. that contain *ListView*

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

---

Here is the *fragment_details.xml* file. that contains one *TextView*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

---

### **Java Files**

Here is the *ListFrag.java* file.

```
ItemSelected activity;
public interface ItemSelected
{
    void onItemSelected(int index);
}
public ListFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (ItemSelected) context;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        data.add(i + ". This is item " + i);
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(@NonNull ListView l, @NonNull View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    activity.onItemSelected(position);
}
```

---

Here is the *DeatailFrag.java* file.

```
public DetailFrag(){
    super(R.layout.fragment_detail);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}
```

---

Here is the *MainActivity.java* file. when I want to access the ID "tvDescription" then it's showing ERROR: *@layout/activity_main does not contain a declaration with id tvDescription.*

**Please help me. How can I access the ID? Tell me which one is the way to find IDs.**

```
TextView tvDescription;
ArrayList<String> description;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        description.add("Description for item " + i);
    }
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int index) {
    tvDescription.setText(description.get(index));
```

}

---

### **Please run this code in your IDE.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your activity and fragment are different classes. And although it is obvious that they represent a single view tree, in fact, in each component class, you should refer to the elements of only its layout.

Thus you need to use

```
TextView tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
```

Directly in the DeatailFrag.onViewCreated after super.onViewCreated

And then, somehow pass the received value back to the activity, if necessary

Happy learning

Comment: please tell me how to back to the activity.

Comment: its many ways to do this. top correct IMO is via ViewModel and LifeData
1) with callbacks
2) with return value options

incorrect, but fast:
3) you can make it with creating static value in your activity and initialize it from fragment
4) you can cast context in fragment to your activity like this: (MainActivity) context
and do whatever u want.
but last two options are bad experience) better not to do like this